# Jade Template - SELECT OPTION with for

Tags: node.js, express, pug

```
select(id="xxx", name="xxxyyy")
- for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){
  option(value="#{i}") Some value for #{i}
- }
```

but it generates the following HTML

```
<select id="xxxx" name "xxxyyy"></select>
<option value="1">Some value for 1</option>
```

....

I've tried to include the select inside the for loop and it works as expected (it generates 10 select drop controls with one item on each one of them).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you've got your indentation messed up. Jade is like coffeescript, in that indentation is significant and donates nesting. See [here](http://www.techthali.org/jade-the-template-engine/). So that the Jade engine knows that your option loop should be within the select tag, the option loop needs to be indented from the select statement, whereas you've got yours level with the select statement.

```
select(id="xxx", name="xxxyyy")
    -for(var i = 1;i<10;i++){
    option(value="#{i}") Some value for #{i}
    -}
```

Comment: Yes sir, that was it. Thank you very much for taking the time to respond.